# How to check the currently used repositories in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

I want to add some logic to the `repositories` closure in the `build.gradle`. Here is an example:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    if( project.hasProperty( 'jboss' ) ) {
        maven { url "http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/" }
    }
}
```

So, to make sure that my settings are working, I want to have a way to check the currently used repositories. How can I achieve that? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way. Below is the code that illustrates the method:

```
task hello << {
    repositories.each {
        println it.url
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It was careless to have a println there.